# Variable switch mode power supply design problem

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, stability

I have an issue understanding the working of a variable switch mode power supply. The power supply uses the reference voltage at the potentiometer and transfers into the VFB or feedback. Suppose I adjusted the potentiometer of the power supply so that I get a 10V at the output. The voltage is set. Now I change the load, suppose the voltage drops then the threshold voltage will become changed, the optocoupler moves the new voltage value back and the PWM duty cycle increased back. But as the PWM duty cycle increases, the reference voltage gets back to normal, so the PWM has to be adjusted again and again. This will make the output oscillatory, and we won't be able to get stable voltage. How does the supply then work in giving a stable output? Kindly help me clear up the confusion.

Comment: Hahaha yikes, that circuit has multiple critical issues. It's a smoke generator, if it starts up at all.

Comment: haha I just wanted to give a reference sir

Comment: The thing to remember is that the output cannot change instantaneously - it may take a number of cycles so this forms an integral term. You might want to research some control theory to better understand feedback loops.

Comment: @kam1212 confused now. Does the picture have anything to do with what you're talking about? If not, remove it. An illustration that illustrates something else is worse than *no* illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is good. It seems like the feedback correction will never stabilize. And, in fact, there are stringent requirements that the feedback has to meet, or, it will behave just as you described.  The two main requirements are :  you can’t have too much gain between the correction and the feedback, and.. you can’t have too much time delay between the correction signal and the sensing of the output.  If Either of these conditions hold, the power supply will oscillate. But if the gain is low enough and the delay is low enough, it will work just fine.

Comment: One way I can think of is that for the first time as the voltage drops the error amplifier increases the voltage to make it stable, but as the voltage gets stable the reference gets back to 2.5V. Now the controller again will try to decrease the duty cycle but as it will decrease the reference would decrease again,therefore it won't able to decrease. Sir I am not getting a proper intuition about this anywhere if you could explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

It won’t necessarily oscillate in the way that you describe.  In many cases the response time of the feedback circuit is shorter than the PWM cycle time, so the switcher won’t over-correct.

Comment: But even after some time, it will try to change its pwm cycle. After the feedback signal reaches the IC

Comment: @kam1212 Unless you have a full PID regulator, a little voltage drop remains under load.

Comment: Then how does an smps works. They are very stable without any advance circuitry l.just using the same feedback and changes it's duty cycle accordingly.

Comment: "without any advance circuitry" What do you think that these ICs are? and what that feedback is used for?